# With storyboards, how can I perform a reverse segue to return to the previous screen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

Currently, I am working on a project which requires multiple screens. When I transition from one screen to another, the default transition when pressing a button is the next screen rising upwards to cover the previous screen. Naturally, when I press a "back" button, I would like the reversal of this segue, where the screen falls downwards, reveling the previous screen. I have tried to devise some code for this to happen:

**Code**
[image: Code]

Whenever I link a "back" button to this action segue, and press the button, It will always lead to the very first screen of the game, rather than the previous screen. Currently, I am left with the back buttons leading towards the previous screen, creating a very unnatural feel to the game, as it appears that all the screens are layering on top of one another. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

Comment: Typically a `dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` is used for modally presented controllers. As a sidenote, a 'back' button is usually associated with a navigation controller whereas a 'close' one most commonly used on modals. I hope that this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code need to be changed as:

```
@IBAction func unwindSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

Use `segue` instead of `sender` in your action.

If you are presenting a `ViewController` you need to dismiss the current `ViewController`

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or if you're in a navigation controller you can "pop" it:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I should mention I have no previous programming experience in any language.

Comment: I tried to interpret what you have done, and I ended up with:                                    @IBAction func unwindSegue(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }